# is it possible to pass class parameter in the function?

Tags: python

im trying to write a class and function for that class. Class has some parameters and i want my function to change specific parameter, which i want to pass as argument to the function.

```
class Army:
    def __init__(self, army_name, slot_1=None):
        self.army_name = army_name
        self.slot_1 = slot_1

    def add_unit_to_army(self, unit, count, slot_number):
        if slot_number == 1 and self.slot_1 is None:
            self.slot_1 = {unit: count}
```

for now its the best solution i was able to get. Can i use somehow slot_1 as parameter for add_unit_to_army function?

so if it would be a lot of slots - it will be a lot of elif.
for now its the best solution i was able to get. Can i use somehow slot_1 as parameter for function like so:

```
a = Army('new Army')
a.add_unit_to_army('skeleton', 33, slot_13)
a.add_unit_to_army('skeleton', 33, slot_34)
```

Comment: Use a list or a dict instead of numbered variables.

Comment: Use a `dict`, it's what they're for: Setting values with arbitrary keys. `self.slot[1] = { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list and append each unit to it but if you want to insert units into arbitrary slots a dictionary would be better:

```
class Army:
    def __init__(self, army_name):
        self.army_name = army_name
        self.slots = dict()

    def add_unit_to_army(self, unit, count, slot_number):
        if slot_number not in self.slots.keys():
            self.slots[slot_number] = (unit, count) #or use a custom object
        else:
            #do whatever you want in case of a collision
```

And then you would insert them like this:

```
a = Army('new Army')
a.add_unit_to_army('skeleton', 33, 13)
a.add_unit_to_army('skeleton', 33, 34)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Army:
def __init__(self, army_name, num_slots=5):
    self.army_name = army_name
    self.slots = [None] * num_slots
```

I made it by list of dicts, Thanks!